# When showing that the policy improvement theorem applies to MC control, why is $q_{\pi_{k}}\left(s, \pi_{k}(s)\right) \geq v_{\pi_{k}}(s)$ true?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proofs, monte-carlo-methods, policy-improvement-theorem

When discussing why the policy improvement theorem is true, when we do Monte Carlo control by updating greedily, it says on [page 98 of Sutton and Barto's book (2nd edition)](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf#page=120) that:

$$
\begin{aligned} 
q_{\pi_{k}}\left(s, \pi_{k+1}(s)\right) 
&=
q_{\pi_{k}}\left(s, \underset{a}{\arg \max } q_{\pi_{k}}(s, a)\right) 
\\ 
&=
\max _{a} q_{\pi_{k}}(s, a) 
\\ 
& 
\geq 
q_{\pi_{k}}\left(s, \pi_{k}(s)\right) 
\\ 
& 
\geq v_{\pi_{k}}(s) \end{aligned}
$$

I don't understand why the last inequality is not an equality.

The policy improvement theorem was derived [on page 78](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf#page=100) for deterministic policies.

So, the $\pi_{k}(s)$ we see in $q_{\pi_k}(s, \pi_{k}(s))$ is a fixed action, call it $a'$. Then, in this case, since $v_{\pi_k}(s)= \sum_a \pi_k(a|s) q_{\pi_k}(s, a) =   1 * q_{\pi_k}(s, a') = q_{\pi_k}(s, a')$ (where the second equality is because the probability of all other actions is 0), shouldn't the last inequality be an equality? When is it possible that we have a greater than relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the strict equality $q_\pi(s,\pi(s)) = v_\pi(s)$ is generally true for a deterministic policy $\pi$.

The $\geq$ inequality is also correct, of course, and it *could be* that the authors' intention was to show that $\pi_{k+1}$ and $\pi_k$ satisfy the condition for the policy improvement theorem:

> Let $\pi$ and $\pi'$ be any pair of deterministic policies such that, for all $s\in\mathcal{S}$,
> $$q_\pi(s,\pi'(s))\geq v_\pi(s)\tag{4.7}$$

So they kinda relaxed the equality to show that the condition is satisfied "word-for-word" for $\pi'=\pi_{k+1}$ and $\pi=\pi_k$.

Although, I must say that they don't seem to be consistent in this - for example, they keep the strict equality at the derivation at the bottom of the page 78. So it might as well be that you've discovered a typo in Sutton and Barto.